# influence of array pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, pointers

When we have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    cout << a[0] << endl;
}
```

I get "1".

But when I change it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    int* b = &a[0];
    cout << a[0] << endl;
    cout << *b << endl;     
}
```

I get something like "-1219451320", which changes after each run.

What was the influence of `b` variable so `a[0]` got changed? For example now, If I change it to previous code, the result will be "1" again.

in both of the states, the array was not initialized! so there shouldn't be difference like this. for example in the first code, if we got "-12242311231", it wouldn't be strange but now ...

Comment: It's undefined behaviour anyway to evaluate elements of an uninitialised array...

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined. You cannot read uninitialized variables and expect a program's behaviour to make sense.

Comment: This is not really undefined behaviour. The values are indeterminate, but evaluating those elements will actually yield these indeterminate values, and evaluating them ten times during the same program run will yield ten times the same value, all this according to the standard. Were the behaviour undefined, we would not be able to say this.

Comment: You right but the point is why it doesn't show its determinacy while not using array pointer. in both of the states , the array is uninitialized and values should be indeterminate.

Comment: @Gorpik: The standard is quite clear on this: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of an uninitialised object gives undefined behaviour (according to C++11 4.1/1).

Comment: @MikeSeymour OK, but 8.5/11 states: *if no initialization is performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value*. I understand this as meaning that the object (in this case, the `int`s inside the array) is initialised with an indeterminate value and can no longer be consider unitialised.

Answer (score 5):

You have not initialized the array, so the values are (or can be) *arbitrary*.

The standard calls them **indeterminate values**.

With two different programs, which you have, you can expect to get two different values, or the same value, with no discernible pattern or reason (it's arbitrary). You can even get different values from two runs of the *same* program. To initialize, just write

```
int a[100] = {};  // All zeroes. :-)
```

Instead of raw arrays, consider using **`std::vector`**, e.g.

```
#include <vector>

// ...
std::vector<int> a( 100 );    // All zeroes
```

It initializes automatically and always.

And it can also be resized.

Comment: I know where it comes from. my main question is that: without using array pointer, despite not being initialized , we get "1" for ever. but after using array pointer, we get "1219451320" which changes after each run. what's the difference? in both of them, the array was not initialized!!

Comment: It's just that it's a different program. Don't even expect the first one to always produce "1".

Comment: Undefined behavior is defined as "behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements." There is no requirement for it to or for it to not run the same every time.

Comment: @user554403 The array was not initialised by you, but the runtime initialises it to whatever it wants. The runtime, not the compiler, so you can run the same program ten times and get ten different values.

Comment: no, it has produced "1" _every time you have run it so far, on your machine or machines_. It could change at any time. It could change if you update your compiler or OS. It could change if you run on a different machine, or during a full moon.

Comment: @Pooya: That probably means that the program's startup code happens to write the value 1 in the memory location that gets reused by the first array element, and declaring an extra variable moves the array to a location it didn't write to. There's no requirement for undefined behaviour to give a different result each time.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I think the question got solved by your comment about lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of an uninitialised object. thank bro :)